How to control the visibility in the screenflow using the picklist value on the same screen and build logic based on the selected value?
I have a picklist that is getting the choices form the Get Record element, based on the value of the picklist I want to control the visibility of a Checkbox on the screen, also for the Value of the checkbox I want to get additional data from the record of the selected value.
I want to know if I can this functionality by just using the Flow Builder? If so how?

Get Program Enrolment is getting multiple record and the picklist is based on it and is used in the Initial Screen Element, I tried to use the Record Choice Set to get additional field values but that did not worked.


Check If this may help you. - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DwZOKSA3

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_visibility_record_field_values.htm&release=240&type=5


@TusharJadav Thanks for the reply, but my situation is different I want to use the selected record fields for controlling the visibility and value of a checkbox on Initial Screen.

Reactivity is the approach, you might have to rework your flow some to get there.
